# Parsing a cut-delim text in shell arrays

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, line

I want to parse a txt file with delimiters and assign it to an array.

Sample text file looks like:

```
create_tetro.c:132://   printf("\t\t\tSol %d found !\n", sol);
float_to_int.c:23://    printf("%f -> %d\n", i, ((int)i / 1) + 0.9999);
free_all.c:19:  printf("update_pieces\n");
```

All .gres*.txt are the exact same files but I didn't find a way to do it only in one loop. Yet, when I try `echo ${array[2]}`, it just shows me blank.
Came up with this so far:

`#!/bin/bash`

```
IFS='\n'
i=0

typeset -a file
typeset -a line_nb=()
typeset -a string=()

while read line; do
{
file[i]="$(cut -d ':' -f1)"
((i++))
}
done < .gres.txt

while read line; do
line_nb[$i]="$(cut -d ':' -f2)";
let i=i+1;
done < .gres2.txt

while read line; do
string[i]="$(cut -d ':' -f3)"
let "i++"
done < .gres3.txt
```

Comment: Edit your question, and post a sample input file (for example only the first three lines). Moreover, limit your post to one question (maybe the `sed` part should be removed, and asked later, in a new question, if needed). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @gsamaras thank you. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally sure about what you need, but right now, cut won't do much and each array starts at an index after the other. You might have a better result with something like that :

```
    #!/bin/bash

    i=0

    while read line; do
    {
    file[$i]="$(cut -d ':' -f1 <<< $line)"
    line_nb[$i]="$(cut -d ':' -f2 <<< $line)"
    string[$i]="$(cut -d ':' -f3 <<< $line)"
    ((i++))
    }
    done < ./gres.txt
```

Hope it could help

Comment: Thank you @Andre Gelinas, it grandly helped me. I noticed that the backslashes for my \n located at the end of my printfs in the txt.file all disappeared when I echo {string[$x]} for example. Is there a way to keep them in the result ? I've found [^\n\r] which is the equivalent of regex '.' but didn't succeed at inserting it correctly.

Comment: thanks Andre. But the -r flag adds a newline in my output whereas I want to keep the format '\n', with both the \ and the n. Any other idea? :)

Comment: No the -r flag makes read not "eating" the \. When you output you need to put the variable within double quotes like : `echo "${string[*]}"` and then you'll see the actual \t and \n.

Comment: Thank you so much Andre